# Can I append Icons in JavaScript as text content

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, css-selectors

I have button which is created using JavaScript

```
const deleteButton = document.createElement('button')
```

I want  to append the delete/trash Icon, the below code is working

```
deleteButton.classList.add('far', 'fa-trash-alt')
```

but the Thing is I only want to append the icon only, rather then a button, can anyone know  how we can do it, but catch is it should be button because the button has assigned to function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a span instead a button, try this:

```js
let deleteSpan = document.createElement('span');
deleteSpan.classList.add('far', 'fa-trash-alt')
```